# conditionally adding columns to a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes with either 2 or 4 columns.

```
a <- data.frame(a=1:10,
                b=1:10,
                c=1:10,
                d=1:10)

b <- data.frame(a=1:10,
                b=1:10)

list_of_df <- list(a,b)
```

I want to add 2 empty columns to each dataframe with only 2 columns.

I've tried this lapply approach:

```
lapply(list_of_df, function(x) ifelse(ncol(x) < 4,x%>%add_column(empty=NA),x <- x))
```

Which does not work unfortunately. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with something similar:

```r
add_col <- function(x){
  col_to_add <- 4 - ncol(x)
  if(col_to_add == 0) return(x)
  z <- rep(NA, nrow(x))
  for (i in 1:col_to_add){
    x <- cbind(x, z)
  }
  x
}

lapply(list_of_df, add_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for loop to avoid copying the whole list:

```
for (i in seq_along(list_of_df)) {
  n_columns = ncol(list_of_df[[i]]) 
  if (n_columns == 2L) { 
    list_of_df[[i]][c('empty1', 'empty2')] <- NA
  }
}
```

Result:

```
> list_of_df
[[1]]
    a  b  c  d
1   1  1  1  1
2   2  2  2  2
3   3  3  3  3
4   4  4  4  4
5   5  5  5  5
6   6  6  6  6
7   7  7  7  7
8   8  8  8  8
9   9  9  9  9
10 10 10 10 10

[[2]]
    a  b empty1 empty2
1   1  1     NA     NA
2   2  2     NA     NA
3   3  3     NA     NA
4   4  4     NA     NA
5   5  5     NA     NA
6   6  6     NA     NA
7   7  7     NA     NA
8   8  8     NA     NA
9   9  9     NA     NA
10 10 10     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `bind_rows` and then `group_split` and `map` from `purrr` to remove the `id_Group` column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_rows(list_of_df) %>% 
  group_split(id_Group =cumsum(a==1)) %>% 
  map(., ~ (.x %>% ungroup() %>% 
              select(-id_Group)))
```

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
       a     b     c     d
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10    10

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
       a     b     c     d
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1    NA    NA
 2     2     2    NA    NA
 3     3     3    NA    NA
 4     4     4    NA    NA
 5     5     5    NA    NA
 6     6     6    NA    NA
 7     7     7    NA    NA
 8     8     8    NA    NA
 9     9     9    NA    NA
10    10    10    NA    NA
```